# SQL2005 Index exists in sys.indexes but not on table

Tags: sql-server-2005, index-tuning, nonclustered-index

I have a routine that runs through all the non-clustered indexes in a given database on SQL2005 (SP3), and reorganizes and rebuilds them (if fragmentation > 20%).  This process is erroring out on one index entry in sys.indexes.  The index does not exist on the database in question, but still exists by name in sys.indexes.

My questions:

1. Is there a way to find other such indexes in all databases?
2. Is it safe to just delete the absent index(es) from sys.indexes?  If not, how do I clean this up?

As always, thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Is the index a "hypothetical index"  (left by the database tuning advisor)?

Comment: @MartinSmith no, this was a real index that did exist once upon a time (according to documentation I can find)

Comment: Is it an index in "disabled" state then?

Comment: nope.  the index does not exist at all